# I wanted to know the command to check if all the values in one field of a table is present in another table under a different field name

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. I want to find out whether the values present in the first table is there in another table with a different field name.

Here is how it looks,

Table1
BillNo
43529179
43256787
35425676
25467778
24354758
45754748

Table2
BNo
113104808
25426577
268579679
2542135464
252525232
235263663

I have 137 records in table1 that needs to be checked against table2.
Instead of doing it one by one using the following command,

Select * from Table2 where BNo = '43529179';

This gives the result for just the mentioned value. Is there a way to check for all the values in a single query?

Thanks!

Comment: Using a join, probably a left one?

Comment: Since you have created an identical question to this one I assume the response did not answer your question. That is probably because your question is too vague. Without knowing what your table structures are like and what you are trying to do the best we can do is guess. This isn't difficult at all once we have the details. I have to say that your data appears to be in serious need of normalization though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-select to compare against:

```
Select * from Table2 where BNo IN (SELECT BillNo FROM Table1);
```

That will "evalaute" to something like  `Select * from Table2 where BNo IN (113104808, 25426577, 268579679, 2542135464, 252525232, ...);`

Comment: Why not just a join on BNo = BillNo?

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables, and check how many matching records there are:

```
select
  count(*) as Matches
from
  Table1 as t1
  inner join Table2 as t2 on t2.BNo = t1.BillNo
```

You can also use a left join to pick out the records in table 1 that has no matching record in table 2:

```
select
  t1.BillNo
from
  Table1 as t1
  left join Table2 as t2 on t2.BNo = t1.BillNo
where
  t2.BNo is null
```