# How to add values from one field in a table to another field in a different table using a common field?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. I want to update a field in `Table2` with the values from another field in `Table1` by using `BNo` field as the link between the two tables.

Table 1

```
Bill No    Fee
25454747   4.67
25376488   6.54
23526777   3.22
```

Table2

```
BNo        Fees
12456436   NULL
21415262   NULL
12426547   NULL
23526777   NULL
```

Here, I need to copy the value of `Fees` from `Table1` and put it in `Table2` against the correct `BillNo`.

`BillNo` in `Table1` and `BNo` in `Table2` has the same values but they are not in the same order.

Comment: This looks just like your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330052/i-wanted-to-know-the-command-to-check-if-all-the-values-in-one-field-of-a-table

Comment: Will the same query work? That was to find out if a value in a field is present in the another table. Here I want to update a field in one table with  values from another table. How do I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UPDATE` with `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE  T2
SET     T2.[Fee] = T1.[Fee]
FROM    [Table2] T2
INNER JOIN [Table1] T1
        ON T1.[BillNo] = T2.[BNo]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE Table2 SET Fees = (SELECT Fee FROM Table1 WHERE BillNo = BNo)
```